# Prove or Disprove: Countable Linear Dense Order Set Are Isomorphic. The specific example of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$

Tags: logic

In our logic quiz, I encounter this specific problem.

> Prove that
>   $$\mathbb{Q} \text{ and } \mathbb{Q} - \{0\} \text{ are order-isomorphic}.$$

It took me a long time to come up the bijection, which is not even correct. But here is some idea. We all know that $\sqrt{2}$ is not inside $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers. We want to make the set of rational number map to $0,$ by centering at square root $2.$ But if we map them by constructing similar triangles, we will get into troubles, which will prevent us from finding the right bijection. My question will be: what is the exact formula of the bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} - \{0\},$ which preserves order?

Comment: See http://blog.jpolak.org/?p=1893 ... Cantor showed that any countable dense linear order without endpoints is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.  @Surb: it says "order-isomorphic" in the text.

Comment: There likely isn't a simple formula for an isomorphism between those ordered sets. The usual way to prove it is by a "back-and-forth" construction in which you build the map inductively. At a typical stage, you've mapped $n$ points in each set, preserving order of course, then take a new point in one set and find a point in the other set similarly located value amongst the already assigned points. By going back and forth, using a countable listing of each set, you assure the map is surjective. But you make arbitrary choices along the way, so there's no final formula for the isomorphism.

Comment: @Surb: an order-isomorphism has to preserve second-order properties like completeness.

Comment: @Surb: Note the word "countable" in what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Pick a rational sequence $r_n$ which is decreasing ro $\sqrt{2}$.

You can find a linear  order isomorphism between $(1, \infty) \cap \mathbb Q$ and $(r_1, \infty) \cap \mathbb Q$.

You can find a linear order isomorphism between $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}] \cap \mathbb Q$ and $(r_{n+1}, r_n] \cap \mathbb Q$ .

By glueing them together, you get a order isomorphism between 
$$(0, \infty) \cap \mathbb Q \mbox{ and } (\sqrt{2}, \infty) \cap \mathbb Q$$

Now, repear the process from the left to construct a order isomorphism between 
$$(-\infty,0) \cap \mathbb Q \mbox{ and } (- \infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb Q$$

Comment: How do you show that there is an order isomorphism between $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}] \cap \mathbb Q$ and $(r_{n+1}, r_n] \cap \mathbb Q$?

Comment: @ZackNi: Since all four endpoints are rationals, you can just interpolate linearly.

Comment: Cantor's back-and-forth argument seems much more general and memorable than this approach to me.

Comment: @ZackNi Bi linear I mean $f(x)=ax+b$. This works since all end points are rational.

Comment: @N.S. I see how it works now.